# getSignalbars API in Win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

getSignalbars API is used in Windows 8.1 to determine the number of signal bars in numeric format. However, it is showing only '5' (highest value) by default when utilized in Win 10. Solution please!

Comment: Please explain better what you have tried so far and if possible post some of your code.

Comment: I am currently using this.

 if (connectionProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile)
                {
                    SignalStrength = Convert.ToInt32(connectionProfile.GetSignalBars());
                }

This gives a correct numeric value for Win 8.1 (i.e how may signal bars are present at that moment from 1 to 5) . 
But for Win 10 it is only showing the highest value i.e. 5

Comment: Please add your comment as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Windows 10 Mobile with ConnectionProfile.GetSignalBars for a mobile broadband connection (GetSignalBars works fine for wifi). It is being investigated for a fix in future versions.

Comment: Now is the future. Any updates?